# How do I set a formatting standard in my worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

We're doing an inventory at work and if this is possible it would save a HUGE amount of time.

If I have 2 columns with numbers, Column A being the recommended amount and column B being the actual amount, is there a way of formatting Column B with greater than, less than and equal to Column A with out doing each separately/manually?

For e.g:

```
Column A    Column B  
1            1 (green)  
4            3 (red)  
25           27 (green)
```

Sorry if the question has already been asked.

Comment: You need conditional formatting ,, better share some sample data wit us!!

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to do this automatically? Instead of using conditional formatting on every cell?

Comment: Doesn't need to apply cell by cell, you can select your whole column and apply formatting at once

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it with conditional formatting:

- select the column you want to format (column B in the example screenshot)
- select "conditional formatting" - "new rule" - "use a formula ..."
- enter the formula: `=B2>=A2`

  - *(note that formula need to refer to the active cell (`B2` in address bar of screenshot))*
- set desired format (green)
- repeat for red formatting too

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this possible to do in Excel online?

Answer (score 3):

@hackerNuB

It is possible. We need to create 3 rules in Excel online. But we could not manage the rules when data increased. If condition allows, I suggest you refer to Máté Juhász’s reply.

**Step 1** ：Select the range that your want to highlight. In the following sample, I select from B1 to B3.

**Step 2** :Click Conditional Formatting in Table group > Highlight Cells Rules > Greater Than. Enter “**=A1**”, choose "Green Fill```".

[image]

**Step 3** :Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Equal to. Enter “**=A1**”, choose Green Fill ```".

[image]

**Step 3** :Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cells Rules > Less Than. Enter “**=A1**”, choose "Light Red Fill ```".

[image]

Then we get it.

[image]